# multithreading class (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

If I have a class that got threading.Thread I run the new thread with **.start()**

```
class hello(threading.Thread):
    def run():
        print "hi"
        print "bye"
```

So this is a thread but when I want 2 threaded functions inside a single class? How do I do that?

Because when you use **.start()** It uses the **run** function in a new thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `target` attribute to the `Thread` constructor instead:

```
class twothreads:
    def t1(self):
        print "Hi"

    def t2(self):
        print "Bye"

t = twothreads()
threading.Thread(target=t.t1).start()
threading.Thread(target=t.t2).start()
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it could be used that way